# Ionic - Sending a whatsapp does not work, only in IOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, whatsapp

Hello I have a problem whit Ionic, I have a button with a link to send a whatsapp, for android works perfectly. But IOS does not open the conversation.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<a [href]=“makeUrl(propiedad)”>
<button class=“button-footer”>
<ion-icon class=“icon-footer” name=“logo-whatsapp”>
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
this.trustedDashboardUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(“whatsapp://send?text=hello&phone=”+AppSettings.whatsapp+"&abid="+AppSettings.whatsapp);
return this.trustedDashboardUrl;
```

**CONFIG XML:**

```
<access launch-external=“yes” origin=“whatsapp:" />
<allow-intent href="whatsapp:” />
```

Comment: the same problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if thats the right way to send a whatsapp message ... 
check the [Social Share Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/)

Comment: In Android works, but doesn't work in IOS platform, If you do not have the saved contact the plugin does not work, I need it to be sent to anyone